# Uso de enum nos cases de um switch

Tags: java, enums

Olá, boa tarde.

Estou com um problema em relação a utilização do ENUM para substituir um número no case. Com o objetivo de deixar meu código mais intuitivo e não utilizar números nos cases do switch, pretendo usar um ENUM no lugar dos mesmos.
Exemplo:

```
private static enum EnumFrutas {
    MACA(0), ABACATE(1), PERA(2);

    public final int codigo;

    EnumFrutas(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return this.codigo;
    }
}

public static LinkedList<LinkedList<Eventos>> Working() {
    switch (Eventos.get(0).getFruta()) {
        case 0: 
            tomaAcaoParaMaçã;
            break;
        case 2: 
            tomaAcaoParaAbacate;
            break;
    }
}
```

Sabendo que `Eventos.get(0).getFruta()` retorna um INT, pretendo usar o valor o qual MACA corresponde no ENUM (no caso, 0) dentro do case:

```
case MACA: 
        tomaAcaoParaMaçã;
        break;
```

De que forma posso fazer isso, já que digitando a palavra MACA em si não funciona?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já tentou :

```
switch (EnumFrutas.values()[Eventos.get(0).getFruta()]) {
      case MACA: 
          tomaAcaoParaMaçã;
          break;
      case ABACATE: 
          tomaAcaoParaAbacate;
          break;
}
```

Assim se `getFruta` for 0 ele vai atras da parte do enum onde o valor é 0 no caso `MACA`

Answer (score 0):

Vou correr o risco de ser negativado fugindo um pouco da sua pergunta, mas sugerindo uma solução melhor para o seu problema.

Que tal forçar no Enum a declaração de uma ação para cada fruta?

```
public interface Action {
   void executa();
}

private static enum EnumFrutas {
    MACA(0, new MacaAction()), 
    ABACATE(1, new AbacateAction()), 
    PERA(2, new PeraAction());

    private int codigo;

    private Action action;

    EnumFrutas(int codigo, Action action) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.action = action;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return this.codigo;
    }

    public Action getAction() {
        return this.action;
    }
}
```

Para executar a ação, você poderá remover o switch problemático, fazendo apenas:

```
public static LinkedList<LinkedList<Eventos>> Working() {
   EnumFruta fruta = Eventos.get(0).getEnumFruta();
    fruta.getAction().executa();
}
```

Comment: 1 problema: memória heap demais alocada pra algo que é usado principalmente para legibilidade ; )

Comment: Discordo. Acho indiferente a questão de memória nesta proposta. Quanto às vantagens, assim você tem maior encapsulamento, não correndo risco de implementar uma ação para uma nova fruta. Se o teu código exige que uma mudança seja feita em vários pontos diferentes para que ela seja propagada, talvez você esteja passando por um problema de projeto.

Comment: Outro ponto, esse enum pode ser usado para outras ações em outros lugares, ter uma ação fixa pra cada pode ser algo usado somente neste ponto. Se você quer um enum com ações genericas encapsuladas ele não precisa ser um enum já que vai deixar de ser legivel.  Ele pode ser uma classe que possui atributos estaticos linkados com Func's que podem ser modificadas conforme a necessidade, ou ainda uma criação de objetos não tipados com Func's. Varia do seu cenário, mas no caso dele não há necessidade para tanto, por isso fazemos um switch, por leibilidade :)